# turbogears querying the database for file

Tags: download, turbogears2

I am using the Turbogears-2.3 framework and now I know how to upload the files in the database using the  tgext.datahelpers. I understand that the file gets uploaded in the disk and in the database the metadata gets stored in the JSON format. Now I want to query the database and wanted that the link to get generated in the file collumn so if someone clicks on it then the file can get downloaded. However when I tried to query the database and viewed the table, in the file column I get text like *trai.model.model.F_AttachedFile object at 0xa7325bac* (trai is the name of the project).
When I iterated through the table and printed the value of the element in the javascript console, the same thing is getting printed. Could anyone please tell me how to generate the downloadable link from this. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that I full understood your question, a little snippet of code might have helped understanding the context, but if I guessed correctly you are trying to the the url of a tgext.datahelpers uploaded file.

In such case see https://bitbucket.org/axant/tgext.datahelpers#rst-header-attachments each attachment `Column` provides an `url` property, so you can get the URL from there.

There is also an example that saves and `Document` model with a `file` field and queries it back printing the url.

Comment: thank you very much for giving this hint. After little manipulation I was able to get the URL. Actually I override the default AttachedFile class but while writing the new F_AttachedFile class, I forgot to add the self.uuid in the self.url parameter. Now I'm able to get the urls. And next task is to make them clickable in the grid display. Could you give any hint on this. Thank you

Comment: if by grid display you mean the TurboGears Admin // CrudRestController you might want to have a look at http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/turbogears/wikier/admin.html#the-slug-column it shows how to display an URL field with a link inside.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll check this solution. However I did it using the jquery.